# Struts 1.x : substring 'script' is removed automatically on from submit

Tags: java, velocity, struts-1

I am facing a crazy issue. On form submit if any word contains 'script' (Eg: De'script'ion) then that will b truncated, hence remaining with 'Deion' ('script' removed from 'Description'). Could not find the reason for it.. I am using Velocity Templates for UI and Struts 1.x

### Form Bean

```
<form-bean name="newUserForm" dynamic="true" type="com.test.fe.webapp.form.NewUserForm">
    <form-property name="userId" type="java.lang.String" />
    <form-property name="role" type="java.lang.String" />
    <form-property name="selectedPartnersMultiSelect" type="java.lang.String[]" />
    <form-property name="isExistingUser" type="java.lang.String" />
</form-bean>
```

Comment: Most web applications have utilities (like a filter on the server side) that checks for bad data like 'script', 'select' etc. Are you sure your web framework does not have anything like that ?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you added `<form-bean>` to an issue which doesn't reference the issue?

Comment: Thanks Guys for your time and reply.. I have added <form-bean> because browser was submitting data propery but when validate() of Form is executed then string got truncated. So I was not sure where exectly issue exists. So I thought there might be some issue in <form-bean> defination.  But later I found that our application has applied a filter to prevent Cross site scripting attacks, hence this issue was occuring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause for this..

Our application has applied a Filter to prevent Cross Site Scripting(XSS) attacks, hence this issue was occuring..

Thanks